# dask distributed grabing all available memory + swap

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, distributed, dask

I am running a pretty simple, or so I think, exercise so I must be doing something really stupid. But I ran out of options..so here is the question.

I am using dask distributed to load data from a parquet table  hive/snappy/80files,400M/rows, 8 columns, of which, out of desperation  I am reading just one column and calculating its sum, to no avail.

I am using memory constrains to forced memory usage low, but such limits are ignored.

```
dask-worker tcp://192.168.33.233:8786 --memory-limit 2e9 --local-directory scratch --nprocs 2 --nthreads 4
```

running on a notebook

```
c=Client("192.168.33.233:8786")

Client
Scheduler: tcp://192.168.33.233:8787
Dashboard: http://192.168.33.233:8787 


Cluster
    Workers: 2
    Cores: 8
    Memory: 4.00 GB

 ddf=dd.read_parquet(os.path.join(parquet_dir,"user_logs.parq"),columns=['num_100'])

%%time
ddf.num_100.sum().compute()
```

At this point the workers will try to take all memory until computer collapses and I get a memory error

Here is a list of packages and versions installed.

## packages in environment at /home/julian/anaconda3/envs/wsm:

#
arrow-cpp                 0.7.0                    py35_2    conda-forge
bkcharts                  0.2                      py35_0
bleach                    1.5.0                    py35_0
bokeh                     0.12.7                   py35_0
certifi                   2016.2.28                py35_0
click                     6.7                      py35_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               0.4.0                    py35_0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0
cython                    0.27                     py35_0    conda-forge
dask                      0.15.2                   py35_0
dask-core                 0.15.3                     py_0    conda-forge
dbus                      1.10.20                       0
decorator                 4.1.2                    py35_0
distributed               1.18.1                   py35_0
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py35_0
expat                     2.1.0                         0
fastparquet               0.1.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.12.1                        3
freetype                  2.5.5                         2
glib                      2.50.2                        1
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         0
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
html5lib                  0.9999999                py35_0
icu                       54.1                          0
ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py35_0
ipython                   6.1.0                    py35_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py35_0
ipywidgets                6.0.0                    py35_0
jedi                      0.10.2                   py35_2
jinja2                    2.9.6                    py35_0
jpeg                      9b                            0
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py35_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3
jupyter_client            5.1.0                    py35_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py35_0
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py35_0
libffi                    3.2.1                         1
libgcc                    5.2.0                         0
libiconv                  1.14                          0
libpng                    1.6.30                        1
libsodium                 1.0.10                        0
libxcb                    1.12                          1
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0
llvmlite                  0.20.0                   py35_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_1
markupsafe                1.0                      py35_0
matplotlib                2.0.2               np113py35_0
mistune                   0.7.4                    py35_0
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
msgpack-python            0.4.8                    py35_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.2.1                    py35_0
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py35_0
notebook                  5.0.0                    py35_0
numba                     0.35.0              np113py35_0
numpy                     1.13.1                   py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0
pandas                    0.20.3                   py35_0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py35_0
parquet-cpp               1.3.0.pre                     2    conda-forge
partd                     0.3.8                    py35_0
path.py                   10.3.1                   py35_0
pcre                      8.39                          1
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py35_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py35_0
psutil                    5.3.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.5.2                    py35_0
py                        1.4.34                   py35_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   0.7.0                    py35_1    conda-forge
pygments                  2.2.0                    py35_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py35_0
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_2
pytest                    3.2.2                    py35_1    conda-forge
python                    3.5.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.1                    py35_0
python-snappy             0.5.1                    py35_0
pytz                      2017.2                   py35_0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py35_0
qt                        5.6.2                         5
qtconsole                 4.3.1                    py35_0
readline                  6.2                           2
requests                  2.14.2                   py35_0
setuptools                36.4.0                   py35_1
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1
sip                       4.18                     py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
snappy                    1.1.6                         0
sortedcontainers          1.5.7                    py35_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0
tblib                     1.3.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.6                      py35_0
testpath                  0.3.1                    py35_0
thrift                    0.10.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.5.18                        0
toolz                     0.8.2                    py35_0
tornado                   4.5.2                    py35_0
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
widgetsnbextension        3.0.2                    py35_0
xz                        5.2.3                         0
yaml                      0.1.6                         0
zeromq                    4.1.5                         0
zict                      0.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11                        0

Comment: I believe there is an incompatibility with the versions of libraries I use. One of them is leaking. Using HDF this does not happens. I tried pyarrow to no avail. There is some UTF encoding issues and it won't work. Still memory limits won't work. I am probably doing something wrong here but the capping is not working as I expected.

Comment: Silly question: does it work if you run the command just once, without `%%time` ?

Comment: I notice you have dask from defaults but dask-core from conda-forge - this is odd.

Comment: @mdurant this is the issue we have been discussing in github/snappy yesterday.  As I mentioned, I think I tracked this this to an issued in dask distributed, in linux. I will rebuild my environment following your comment. I probably tried to install directly from anaconda, when it failed I resorted to conda-forge for some packages. Specifically fastparquet and thrift  from anaconda did not work for me but it did work from conda-forge. I will keep you posted of the new results.

Comment: @mdurant I did a fresh conda install. This time installation went smooth. Results are mixed. In linux, on dask (threading, multiprocess) works well. However far more greedy with  memory than on windows. On dask.distributed it stills blows away. In snappy project, I saw some comments around 2 ways of decompressing. Block and streaming. If block was used, the whole process was more memory hungry. I am going to close the question nevertheless. Though, I still believe there is something fishy.

Answer (score 0):

As @mdurant  mentioned in the comments, the inconsistent installation may have played a role in the problem.

I am assuming that the issue arises from how the parquet/hive file was created. With a large  row_group_offsets, and snappy decompressing them in block, it was larger that can fit into memory.

Recreating the parquet file/hive with row_group_offsets=100K instead of 50M(default), allowed the calculation to proceed.

```
fp.write(os.path.join(parquet_dir,"user_logs.parq"),
                   df,
                   compression="snappy",
                   write_index=True,
                   fixed_text={"msno":44},
                   file_scheme="hive",
                   row_group_offsets=100000,
                   append=True

                  )
```

It is interesting that, after fixing the issue with the libraries, dask.threading/dask.multiprocessing was OK digesting the file with large row_group_offsets. However, in dask.distributed (using local cluster) it would still fail.

Food for thought.